# How to Convert (Monthname,year) in to DateTime Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a function which has a parameter @terminationMonthYear with datatype nvarchar,

i need to convert the above parameter in to datetime.

Eg : If i pass (January,2013) .I need it to convert in to first day of that particular month '2013-01-01' with datetime datatype in sql server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes,it is next to month name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (in this example, @Date represents @terminationMonthYear):

```
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(50) = 'February ,2013'
DECLARE @Month NVARCHAR(50) = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Date, PATINDEX('%,%',@Date)-1)))
DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(50) = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@Date, LEN(@Date) - PATINDEX('%,%',@Date))))
SELECT CAST(@Month + ' 01, ' + @Year AS DATE)
```

OR if your input parameter includes the (), then try this:

```
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(50) = '(February ,2013)'
   SET @Date = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Date,'(',''),')','')
DECLARE @Month NVARCHAR(50) = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Date, PATINDEX('%,%',@Date)-1)))
DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(50) = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@Date, LEN(@Date) - PATINDEX('%,%',@Date))))
SELECT CAST(@Month + ' 01, ' + @Year AS DATE)
```

This will work whether you pass in the full month name or the 3-letter abbreviation (e.g. Mar for March).  Also, you mentioned you wanted to convert it into DATETIME format, but 2013-01-01 is a DATE (no time component).  If you want a time component, you can just change the CAST in the last line to "... AS DATETIME" and it will add a time component (though it will be all 0's).

Comment: That's a lot of parsing :P

Answer (score 1):

if you pass  "Jan,2013" it will work

```
@MonthName  Varchar(50)
Declare @FromDate datetime, @ToDate datetime
Select @FromDate = Convert(Datetime,@MonthName), @ToDate = DateAdd(d,-1,DateAdd(m,1,Convert(Datetime,@MonthName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your format is always going to be "month, year" could you do the following by just replacing the `,` with `01,`:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100)
SET @input = 'January, 2014'
DECLARE @newinput VARCHAR(100) 
SET @newinput = REPLACE(@input, ',', ' 01,')

SELECT CAST(@newinput AS DATETIME)
```

Or if you just want the one liner version:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@input, ',', ' 01,') AS DATETIME)
```

A lot simpler but you need to make sure the format input is correct but you will probably have this issue with almost any type of parsing solution as well.

**EDIT:** Comment was you might need to get rid of the brackets as well so easy enough:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@input, ',', ' 01,'), ')', ''), '(', '') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Nice and concise, still need to account possibly for if the paren's are included in the input :P

Comment: @koppinjo Oh I didn't realize the parens were part of it.  Thought he was using the to group the text to say what the input is... that is just another simple replace of '(' for '' though and vice versa... easy enough to strip off :)

Answer (score 0):

The `convert()` function will convert '01-January-2013' to a valid date. You just need to add the 01 at the beginning of your string and turn the comma into a dash:

```
convert(date, '01-' + replace(@terminationMonthYear, ',', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL CAST function is surprisingly versatile:

```
SELECT CAST('January,2013' AS DATETIME)
```

Returns '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000', which I believe is exactly what you were looking for.
The time information seems redundant though, so consider casting it as DATE instead.